# Create List Item using Microsoft Flow when multiselect field present

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I'm trying to create a new list item when a document is created in specific folder using MS Flow. That part I can get it to work without any issues. But, now there is a field that's a Choice field where I need to use Check boxes (allow multiselect).

This is what I'm doing:
[image]

I'm not sure how to populate the Review Group field's checkboxes. I also tried using array instead of string variable, and it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the "Switch to input entire Array" on your Create action.

Instead of a string, set your `Review Group var` to a type `Array`.  In your `Apply to each`, use the `Append to Array` action to append to your variable.

Then, in your create item action, you need to click the button next to your multi-value field to "Switch to input entire Array" (see screenshot below).  Then you can choose your array variable as dynamic input.

[image: Screenshot of Switch to Input Entire Array]

In fact, if the `Review Group` field in the file item that Triggered your Flow is also a multi-value choice field, you can skip the whole building an array variable process.  After you click the "Switch to input entire Array" button, you can reference that field from the trigger body directly.